# Run java code with jar in terminal

Tags: java, jar, terminal

I have the following .java file:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;

    public class Main 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
```

I am compiling it with: `javac -cp ./commons-cli-1.4.jar Main.java`
But when I try to run it with: `java -cp ./commons-cli-1.4.jar Main` I get the following error: `Could not find or load main class Main`. I know I should give the full class name after the path to the jar file but I do not have any package. All I have on this machine about this project is one directory including .jar file and Main.java and already Main.class. So, I cannot understand what could be the problem...

Comment: You need to include the current directory in the classpath as well. Now the classpath only has the jar file, which doesn't contain `Main`.

Comment: I have tried `java -cp /home/myDir/commons-cli-1.4.jar Main`  and  also    `java -cp /home/myDir/commons-cli-1.4.jar /home/myDir/Main`   but it still returns the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the actual Directory to the classpath too

Windows:

```
 java -cp ./;./commons-cli-1.4.jar Main.java
```

IX:

```
 java -cp ./:./commons-cli-1.4.jar Main.java
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works :)